# Trying to make a sticky header for Tumblr

Tags: html, css, tumblr

I'm not 100% how to do this, I've had some success, but it usually causes something else to mess up. If anyone could help me out here, I would very much appreciate it. :D

Also, I'm just pasting the entire thing, in case alterations are needed. :)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<!--

  Obsidian [version 1.3]
  Tumblr theme by Liam Cooke <http://inky.tumblr.com/>
  Free to use and alter, as long as this message is left intact.

-->
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

    <!-- DEFAULT COLORS -->
    <meta name="color:Background" content="#000000"/>
    <meta name="color:Primary Text" content="#D4DBC7"/>
    <meta name="color:Secondary Text" content="#585F50"/>
    <meta name="color:Post Background" content="#0B0C0A"/>
    <meta name="color:Block Background" content="#10110F"/>
    <meta name="color:Borders" content="#22241C"/>
    <meta name="color:Link" content="#92CF27"/>
    <meta name="color:Link Hover" content="#E08048"/>
    <meta name="color:Link Hover Background" content="#0B0C0A"/>
    <meta name="color:Link Hover Border" content="#22241C"/>
    <meta name="color:Strong Link" content="#EB6111"/>
    <meta name="color:Strong Link Hover" content="#E08048"/>
    <meta name="color:Logo" content="#47403B"/>
    <meta name="color:Logo Hover" content="#EB6111"/>
    <!-- END DEFAULT COLORS -->

    <title>{Title}{block:PostSummary}: {PostSummary}{/block:PostSummary}</title>
    {block:Description}<meta name="description" content="{MetaDescription}" />{/block:Description}
    <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="RSS" href="{RSS}"/>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{Favicon}"/>
    <style type="text/css" media="all">

      /* ----- reset ----- */

      body, div, ul, ol, li, dl, dt, dd,
      h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6,
      p, pre, blockquote, form, fieldset {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

      fieldset, img, abbr, acronym {
        border: 0;
      }

      form, fieldset, input, textarea, button {
        font: inherit;
      }

      cite, code, dfn, var {
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: normal;
      }

      h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
        font-size: 100%;
        font-weight: bold;
      }

      /* ----- base ----- */

      html {
        font-size: 100.01%;
      }

      body {
        background: {color:Background};
        color: {color:Primary Text};
        font: 1em/1.65em;
      }

      p, pre, blockquote,
      h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6,
      ul, ol, li, dl, dt, dd,
      form, fieldset,
      .caption {
        line-height: 1.65em;
      }

      h2 {
        font-size: 1.6em;
        font-variant: small-caps;
        margin: 1.25em 0.625em 0.625em;
      }
      h3 {
        font-size: 1.25em;
        margin: 1.6em 0.8em 0.8em;
      }
      h4 {
        font-size: 1em;
        margin: 2em 1em 1em;
      }

      p, pre {
        margin: 1em;
      }

      ul, ol {
        margin: 1em 1em 1em 3em;
      }

      dl {
        margin: 1em;
      }
      dt {
        font-weight: bold;
        margin: 0;
      }
      dd {
        margin: 0 1em 0.5em 2em;
      }

      blockquote {
        font-style: italic;
        margin: 1em;
        padding: 0 1em;
      }
      blockquote p {
        margin-left: 0;
        margin-right: 0;
      }
      blockquote i, blockquote em {
        font-style: normal;
        letter-spacing: 0.075em;
        padding: 0 0.075em;
      }

      abbr, acronym, .caps {
        font-size: 0.9em;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        letter-spacing: 0.125ex;
      }
      .small-caps {
        font-variant: small-caps;
        letter-spacing: 0.125ex;
      }

      code {
        background: {color:Block Background};
        border: 1px solid {color:Borders};
      }
      pre code {
        display: block;
        overflow-x: auto;
        padding: 0.2em 0.4em;
      }

      input, textarea, button {
        background: {color:Post Background};
        color: {color:Primary Text};
        margin: 0.05em;
        padding: 0 0.05em;
        border: 1px solid {color:Borders};
      }

      #search .submit {
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        visibility: hidden;
        border: none;
      }

      .caption {
        margin: 1em;
      }
      .caption p, .caption pre,
      .caption dl, .caption blockquote {
        margin: 1em 0;
      }

      .caption ul, .caption ol {
        margin: 1em 0 1em 2em;
      }

      .clearing {
        clear: both;
        font-size: 1px !important;
        height: 0;
        line-height: 1px !important;
        overflow: hidden;
      }

      /* ----- layout ----- */

      #header {
        font-size: 3em;
      }

      #tumblelog {
        float: right;
        margin: 3em 0 2em -16em;
        width: 100%;
      }

      #posts {
        margin: 0 1em 0 16em;
      }

      #sidebar-wrap {
        width: 14em;
        float: left;
      }

      /* ----- sidebar ----- */

      #sidebar {
        color: {color:Secondary Text};
        margin: 3em 0 1em 2em;
      }

      #sidebar h2 {
        display: none;
      }

      #sidebar #description {
        margin: 3em 0.5em;
      }

      #sidebar ul {
        margin: 3em 0;
        list-style: "position:fixed";
      }

      #sidebar dl {
        margin: 3em 0;
      }
      #sidebar dt {
        margin: 1em 0 0 0.5em;
      }
      #sidebar dd {
        font-size: 0.9em;
        margin-left: 1.5em;
      }
      #sidebar dl a {
        display: block;
        font-weight: normal;
      }

      #sidebar form {
        padding-right: 2em;
      }

      /* ----- footer ----- */

      #footer {
        clear: both;
        background: {color:Block Background};
        color: {color:Secondary Text};
        font-size: 0.9em;
        padding: 1em 5%;
        border-top: 4px solid {color:Borders};
      }

      #footer ul {
        list-style: none;
        margin: 1em;
      }

      #footer ul li {
        clear: both;
      }

      #footer ul li strong {
        display: inline;
        float: left;
        margin: 0 0 1em;
        text-align: right;
        width: 20%;
      }

      #footer ul li span {
        float: left;
        margin: 0 0 1em;
        padding-left: 1.5em;
        width: 70%;
      }


      /* ----- posts ----- */

      .post {
        max-width: 40em;
        min-width: 500px;
        margin: 0 0 4em;
      }

      .post .body {
        background: {color:Post Background};
        margin: 0 1em;
        padding: 1em 1em 1.5em;
        border: 1px solid {color:Borders};
      }

      .post h2 {
        margin: 0.375em 0.625em 0;
        line-height: 1em;
      }

      .post ul {
        margin-left: 2em;
        list-style: square;
      }
      .post li {
        margin: 0.5em 0;
      }

      .post blockquote {
        padding-left: 1.5em;
        border-left: 0.5em solid {color:Borders};
      }

      .post img {
        max-width: 100%;
      }

      .post .meta {
        color: {color:Secondary Text};
        font-variant: small-caps;
        line-height: 120%;
        margin: 0 1em 0 2em;
        text-align: right;
      }
      .post .meta .wrap {
        font-size: 0.9em;
      }
      .post .meta .date {
        font-variant: small-caps;
      }

      .post hr {
        display: none;
      }

      /* ----- shared post styles ----- */

      .chat, .photo, .video {
        background: transparent !important;
        border-color: {color:Background} !important;
        padding-bottom: 0 !important;
      }

      /* ----- chat posts ----- */

      .chat ul {
        list-style: none;
        margin: 1em -1em 0;
        border: solid {color:Borders};
        border-width: 1px 1px 1px 0.5em;
      }
      .chat li {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 1em 1.5em 1.25em;
      }

      .chat .odd {
        background: {color:Post Background};
      }
      .chat .even {
        background: {color:Block Background};
      }

      .chat .person, .chat .line {
        display: block;
      }
      .chat .person {
        font-size: 1.2em;
      }
      .chat .line {
        padding-left: 1em;
      }

      /* ----- audio posts ----- */

      .audio .embed {
        float: left;
      }

      .audio .details {
        color: {color:Secondary Text};
        float: left;
        font-size: 0.9em;
        font-variant: small-caps;
      }

      /* ----- quote posts ----- */

      .quote blockquote {
        font-style: normal !important;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0 !important;
        border: 0 !important;
      }
      .quote blockquote p {
        font-size: 1.6em;
        line-height: 1.4em !important;
        margin: 0.5em 0.625em 0.625em !important;
      }
      .quote blockquote em {
        font-style: italic !important;
      }

      /* ----- pagination ----- */

      .pagination {
        color: {color:Secondary Text};
        padding: 1px;
      }

      .pagination .page {
        padding: 0.5em;
        text-align: center;
      }

      .pagination .newer, .pagination .older {
        display: inline;
      }

      .pagination .newer {
        float: left;
      }
      .pagination .older {
        float: right;
      }

      /* ----- tags & search pages ----- */

      h3#pagetitle {
        color: {color:Secondary Text};
        font-size: 1.5em;
        line-height: 1.5em;
        margin: 0.25em 2em 1.5em;
      }

      /* ----- fonts ----- */

      body {
        font-family: 'DejaVu Sans', Helvetica,
          Candara, 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif;
      }

      blockquote {
        font-family: 'Lido STF', 'DejaVu Serif', Georgia,
          'Palatino Linotype', serif;
      }

      pre, code {
        font-family: 'DejaVu Sans Mono', 'Courier New', monospace;
      }

      /* ----- links ----- */

      a {
        color: {color:Link};
        font-weight: bold;
        text-decoration: none;
      }
      a:hover {
        color: {color:Link Hover};
        text-decoration: underline;
      }

      a:focus {
        outline: 0;
      }

      #header a {
        background: {color:Logo};
        color: {color:Background};
        display: block;
        font-variant: small-caps;
        height: 0.95em;
        letter-spacing: 0.125ex;
        line-height: 1.25em;
        overflow: hidden;
        padding: 0 0.75em;
      }
      #header a:hover {
        background: {color:Logo Hover};
        color: {color:Background};
        text-decoration: none;
      }

      .post strong a,
      .post .link h2 a {
        color: {color:Strong Link} !important;
      }
      .post strong a:hover,
      .post .link h2 a:hover {
        color: {color:Strong Link Hover} !important;
      }

      .post .meta a {
        background: transparent;
        color: {color:Secondary Text} !important;
        padding: 0 0.35em;
      }
      .post .meta a:hover {
        background: {color:Link Hover Background} !important;
        color: {color:Link Hover} !important;
        text-decoration: none !important;
      }

      #pagetitle a {
        color: {color:Secondary Text} !important;
        padding: 0 0.125em;
      }
      #pagetitle a:hover {
        color: {color:Link Hover} !important;
        text-decoration: none !important;
      }

      #navigation a,
      .pagination a {
        background: transparent;
        display: block;
        border: 1px solid {color:Background};
      }
      #navigation a:hover,
      .pagination a:hover {
        background: {color:Link Hover Background};
        text-decoration: none !important;
        border-color: {color:Link Hover Border};
      }

      #navigation a {
        padding: 0.25em 0.5em 0.75em;
        text-transform: lowercase;
      }

      .pagination a {
        padding: 0.5em 1.5em 0.75em;
      }

      {CustomCSS}
    </style>
</head><body>

  <h1 id="header"><a href="/">{Title}</a></h1>

  <div id="tumblelog">
    <div id="posts">

      {block:TagPage}
      <h3 id="pagetitle">{Tag} <a
        href="{TagURL}" title="Browse '{Tag}' posts">&#8600;</a><a
        href="{TagURLChrono}" title="Browse '{Tag}' posts in chronological order">&#8598;</a>
      </h3>
      {/block:TagPage}

      {block:SearchPage}
        <h3 id="pagetitle">‘{SearchQuery}’ ({SearchResultCount})</h3>
      {/block:SearchPage}

      {block:Posts}
      <div class="post {TagsAsClasses}">

        {block:Text}
        <div class="body text">
          {block:Title}
          <h2><a href="{Permalink}">{Title}</a></h2>
          {/block:Title}

          <div class="caption">{Body}</div>
        </div>
        {/block:Text}

        {block:Photo}
        <div class="body photo">
          <p class="image">{LinkOpenTag}<img
          src="{PhotoURL-500}" alt="{PhotoAlt}"/>{LinkCloseTag}</p>

          {block:Caption}
          <div class="caption">{Caption}</div>
          {/block:Caption}
        </div>
        {/block:Photo}

        {block:Quote}
        <div class="body quote {Length}-quote">
          <blockquote><p>{Quote}</p></blockquote>

          {block:Source}
          <p class="source">&mdash; {Source}</p>
          {/block:Source}
        </div>
        {/block:Quote}

        {block:Link}
        <div class="body link">
          <h2><a href="{URL}">{Name}</a></h2>

          {block:Description}
          <div class="caption">{Description}</div>
          {/block:Description}
        </div>
        {/block:Link}

        {block:Chat}
        <div class="body chat">
          {block:Title}
          <h2><a href="{Permalink}">{Title}</a></h2>
          {/block:Title}

          <ul>
            {block:Lines}
            <li class="{Alt} {UserNumber}">
              {block:Label}<strong class="person">{Label}</strong>{/block:Label}

              <span class="line">{Line}</span>
            </li>
            {/block:Lines}
          </ul>
        </div>
        {/block:Chat}

        {block:Audio}
        <div class="body audio">
          <div class="player">
            <p class="embed">{AudioPlayerBlack}</p>
            <p class="details">
              Plays: {PlayCount}
              {block:ExternalAudio}
                &bull; <a href="{ExternalAudioURL}">Download</a>
              {/block:ExternalAudio}
            </p>
            <div class="clearing">&nbsp;</div>
          </div>

          {block:Caption}
          <div class="caption">{Caption}</div>
          {/block:Caption}
        </div>
        {/block:Audio}

        {block:Video}
        <div class="body video">
          <p>{Video-500}</p>

          {block:Caption}
          <div class="caption">{Caption}</div>
          {/block:Caption}
        </div>
        {/block:Video}

        <p class="meta"><span class="wrap">
          <span class="date"><a href="{Permalink}">{DayOfMonth} {Month} {Year}</a></span>

          {block:RebloggedFrom}
          &bull; <span class="reblog">
            reblog: <a href="{ReblogRootURL}" title="{ReblogRootTitle}">{ReblogRootName}</a>
          </span>
          {/block:RebloggedFrom}

          {block:HasTags}
          &bull; <span class="tags">
            {block:Tags} <a href="{TagUrl}">{Tag}</a> {/block:Tags}
          </span>
          {/block:HasTags}
        </span></p>

        <hr/>
      </div>
      {/block:Posts}

      <div class="pagination">
      {block:Pagination}
        {block:PreviousPage}<p class="newer">
          <a href="{PreviousPage}">&laquo; Newer</a>
        </p>{/block:PreviousPage}

        {block:NextPage}<p class="older">
          <a href="{NextPage}">Older &raquo;</a>
        </p>{/block:NextPage}

        <p class="page">{CurrentPage} &#8260; {TotalPages}</p>
      {/block:Pagination}

      {block:PermalinkPagination}
        {block:NextPost}<p class="newer">
          <a href="{NextPost}">&laquo; Newer</a>
        </p>{/block:NextPost}

        {block:PreviousPost}<p class="older">
          <a href="{PreviousPost}">Older &raquo;</a>
        </p>{/block:PreviousPost}
      {/block:PermalinkPagination}

      {block:DayPagination}
        {block:NextDayPage}<p class="newer">
          <a href="{NextDayPage}">&laquo; {DayOfMonth} {ShortMonth}</a>
        </p>{/block:NextDayPage}

        {block:PreviousDayPage}<p class="older">
          <a href="{PreviousDayPage}">{DayOfMonth} {ShortMonth} &raquo;</a>
        </p>{/block:PreviousDayPage}
      {/block:DayPagination}

      {block:DayPage}
        <p class="page">{DayOfMonth} {Month} {Year}</p>
      {/block:DayPage}

        <div class="clearing">&nbsp;</div>
      </div><!-- /pagination -->

    </div><!-- /posts -->
  </div><!-- /tumblelog -->

  <div id="sidebar-wrap" style="position:fixed"> <!-- erase if sticky no longer needed -->
    <div id="sidebar">
      <h2>Info</h2>

      <p id="description">{Description}</p>

      <ul id="navigation">
        <li><a href="http://questioneverythingtrustno1.tumblr.com/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/archive">Archive</a></li>
        <li><a href="/ask">Seek</a></li>
        <li><a href="{RSS}">Subscribe</a></li>
      </ul>



        <!--

        <dt>links</dt>
        <dd><a href="http://">Link 1</a></dd>
        <dd><a href="http://">Link 2</a></dd>

        -->
      </dl>

    </div>
  </div><!-- /sidebar -->

  <div class="clearing">&nbsp;</div>

  <footer>
  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="http://questioneverythingtrustno1.tumblr.com/">Jump to Top</a>
</footer>
    <br>
</body></html>
```

Comment: `position:fixed;` is what you need to make something static

Comment: I have absolutely no idea where it needs to go.... :(

Comment: right click->inspect element in chrome, on the item you want to be stickied

Comment: Awesome, I was able to get it. Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: glad to be of assistance ^^

Comment: Glad this is sorted, can @HC_ post the answer and can the OP accept it so we can close this.

Comment: @user3120793 if you'd like, you can click the checkmark by my answer to officially accept it :)

Answer (score 1):

Apply `position: fixed;` to an element that you want stickied. To find that element, right click->inspect element in Google Chrome or Firefox.